# Экранирование символов для комментариев

Tags: mysqli

Когда я добавляю комментарии в базу, я экранирую все плохие символы. Вот такой код:

mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($text)))

Но тут я заметил, что если в тексте встретится символ „+“, то он превратится в пробел и так запишется в базу. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не в тексте плюс, а Вы получаете `$text` из адресной строки, а плюс в адресе это пробел.

Comment: Вот оно что. Об этом я и не подумал, т.е. стоит экранировать „+“ еще до передачи в скрипт.
Это единственный символ, который может потеряться?

Comment: Нагуглил функцию encodeURIComponent() в JS. Кажется, она полностью подходит. На стороне сервера ничего не придется декодировать?

Comment: На стороне сервера все будет нормально.